# underscore _.delay implementation

Tags: javascript, delay

Why does the first implementation of delay not work?

Also how does the 3rd one work without using Array.prototype.slice.call?

```
  _.delay = function(func, wait) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return setTimeout(func(args), wait);
  };

  _.delay = function(func, wait) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return setTimeout(function() { return func.apply(this, args); }, wait);
  };

  _.delay = function(func, wait) {
    return setTimeout.apply(this, arguments);
  };
```

Comment: 4th one: `_.delay = setTimeout` :-)

Comment: Oops, actually the third and fourth don't work: `WRONG_THIS_ERR`. You'll need to use `.apply(window, arguments)` or `_.delay = setTimeout.bind(window)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the first implementation of delay not work?

Because `setTimeout(func(args), wait);` calls the `func`tion. Right now. Before it's passing the result of the call to `setTimeout`. But that does expect a callback function to call later!

> Also how does the 3rd one work without using Array.prototype.slice.call?

Because [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) does also accept [`arguments` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) directly, not only arrays. However, I guess you actually wonder why

```
_.delay = function(func, wait, ...args) {
    return setTimeout(func, wait, ...args); // using rest arguments
};
```

works? Because that's how [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) handles excess arguments<sup>1</sup> - it passes them to the delayed `func` call.

<sub>1: In most implementations. Old IE didn't.</sub>